# Javascript if statement inside return

Tags: javascript, search, vue.js, filter, return

I need some help. I have an array `allGames` of objects received as a prop from the parent. I need to filter this array based on its objects properties (`venue, date, price`) and so on. The filter values will be entered by the user in either a checkbox, a dropdown or something else. I need these filters to work together.

For that I am using two extra arrays: one called `filteredGames` to hold the games to be displayed after filtering and another one called `searchTerm` that updates as the inputs are entered.

I managed to filter properly using the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="date" v-model="searchTerm.date">
<input type="text" name="venue" v-model="searchTerm.venue">
<input type="text" name="price" v-model="searchTerm.price">

export defaults {
    props: {
      allGames: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        filteredGames: [],
        searchTerm: {
          venue: '',
          date: '',
          price: ''
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      searchTerm: {
        handler: function (val) {
          this.filterGames()
          this.$emit('input', val)
        },
        deep: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      filterGames: function () {
        if (this.filteredGames.length === 0) { this.filteredGames = this.allGames }
        if (this.searchTerm.venue) { this.searchTerm.venue = this.searchTerm.venue.toLowerCase() }
        if (this.searchTerm && this.filteredGames) {
          this.filteredGames = this.allGames.filter(game => {
            return (
              game.venue.toLowerCase().search(this.searchTerm.venue) >= 0 &&
              game.date.search(this.searchTerm.date) >= 0 &&
              game.price.search(this.searchTerm.price) >= 0
            )
          })
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that not all of the original objects' properties are filled. For example, a game may have its `price` column empty. When that happens I get `Error in callback for watcher "searchTerm": "TypeError: game.price is null"` and the search doesn't work at all.

Is there a way to add an `if` statement inside return? Something like `if (game.price) { game.price.search(this.searchTerm.price) >= 0 }`?

I couldn't find a way to make it work. If it's not possible is there an alternative?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You only return in an `if` statement, what about the other branchings? If you always use the returned value then this might be the issue

Comment: It should only return if the user has done changes in the search term and the `filteredGames` array has been defined already. Otherwise it shouldn't return anything. I think it's correct. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, only apply the search if the property is truthy like this:

This is called

> Short-circuit evaluation

```
 return (
      (game.venue && game.venue.toLowerCase().search(this.searchTerm.venue) >= 0) &&
      (game.date && game.date.search(this.searchTerm.date) >= 0) &&
      (game.price && game.price.search(this.searchTerm.price) >= 0)
    );
```

It works because in JavaScript, `true && expression` always evaluates to `expression`, and `false && expression` always evaluates to `false.`

**Edit** Using `||` to return true even if 1 search matches:

```
return (
          (game.venue && game.venue.toLowerCase().search(this.searchTerm.venue) >= 0) ||
          (game.date && game.date.search(this.searchTerm.date) >= 0) ||
          (game.price && game.price.search(this.searchTerm.price) >= 0)
        );
```

**Edit 2** To filter only and all the values entered by the user and ignore the others:

```
return (
        (!game.venue || game.venue.toLowerCase().search(this.searchTerm.venue) >= 0) &&
        (!game.date || game.date.search(this.searchTerm.date) >= 0) &&
        (!game.price || game.price.toString().search(this.searchTerm.price) >= 0)
      );
```

Comment: Right. Thanks, that worked. Now I have another problem. Not sure if it's related to this or not. I'm getting `Error in callback for watcher "searchTerm": "TypeError: game.price.search is not a function"` and the search function doesn't work again. Is there any kind of limitation in the search function as to what types of variables one can use?

Comment: @pharaohlxvi If price is an integer you can do this game.price.toString().search(this.searchTerm.price)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! It's still not giving me exactly what I expected though. When the user adds something to `venue` it shows the games with that value, and that's perfect. The thing is it doesn't show the games that do not have a value in the other fields (for example in the `price`) field, even if the it has the intended `venue`.

Comment: Not sure if it's clear. What I want is that the filter doesn't take into consideration the fileds left empty by the user.

Comment: That wasn't clear by your question, you should be using the || operator instead of && so that even if it finds a match in any of the tree conditions  it return true

Comment: I don't think that's the case. If I do that then it almost always returns all of the games, because likely one of the conditions will be met by all of the games. I need to always filter out whatever doesn't match what's entered by the user.

Comment: Got it I used `(!game.price || (game.price && game.price.toString().search(this.searchTerm.price) >= 0))` with the && connector. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You could have use just (!game.price || game.price.toString().search(this.searchTerm.price) >= 0))