# Is checking for NULL of DOM-element inside return statement of map function possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a little web scraping scipt running which works well for the majority of items until the pattern changes on the website.

Website scraped (terms of use and robots.txt obeyed):
https://www.studycheck.de/hochschulen/fhvr-bayern/bewertungen

It's a german page with student reviews regarding their universities / courses.

In the code below I grab a whole div container with everything I need for every student rating and split that up for a constructor in a map function in the return statement of puppeteers page evaluate function.

Constructor:

```js
function Corpus(course, rating, author, text, date){
      this.course = course;
      this.rating = rating;
      this.author = author;
      this.text = text;
      this.date = date;
    }
```

Function taking up div and returning properties of individual css-selector items:

```js
var getReview = await page.evaluate(() => {
//this querySelectorAll get's the 4 review divs per page
          let reviewBlock = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div [class*='report-item-boxed']"))
  
//now I split up the 5 items I need for my constructor

          return reviewBlock.map(block => [
              block.querySelector(".item-course-title a").textContent.trim(),
              block.querySelector("div .rating-value").textContent.trim(),
              block.querySelector(".item-author").innerText,
              block.querySelector("p.item-text").innerText.trim(),
              block.querySelector('span.item-date').innerText
          ]);
      });
```

That works just fine for all reviews up to an certain age. These older reviews deep into the pagination don't have a element "div .rating-value" and so that .textcontent comes back null and the code breaks.

I tried to put a if(css-element == null){than return "null"} else {map the textcontent as normal) but it throws an error, that the if is an unexpected token in that place...

I tried to understand if these posts here on SO are my problem, but could not figured it out.

[Javascript if statement inside return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608293/javascript-if-statement-inside-return)

[Null check in the return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54893286/null-check-in-the-return-statement)

Should I do any error handling before the return statement and then return an object?

I deeply appreciate any hints how to solve that issue and return a placeholder value in case a selector isn't found / it's property value is null.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not saying that this is the cleanest solution, but in order to fix your problem:

This:

```
      return reviewBlock.map(block => [
          block.querySelector(".item-course-title a").textContent.trim(),
          block.querySelector("div .rating-value").textContent.trim(),
          block.querySelector(".item-author").innerText,
          block.querySelector("p.item-text").innerText.trim(),
          block.querySelector('span.item-date').innerText
      ]);
```

is equivalent to:

```
    return reviewBlock.map(block => {

         // So you can make your if conditions here, 
         // and build the array dynamically before returning it. 

         return [
          block.querySelector(".item-course-title a").textContent.trim(),
          block.querySelector("div .rating-value").textContent.trim(),
          block.querySelector(".item-author").innerText,
          block.querySelector("p.item-text").innerText.trim(),
          block.querySelector('span.item-date').innerText
      ]

    });
```